# New version of Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I will try to use bootstrap 3 datetimepicker in paramquery grid. Please help how can use bootstrap 3 datetimepicker inside paramquery column. I have attached the following js and css files,

```js
          1.9.1.jquery.min.js 
    1.9.2.jquery-ui.min.js 
    pqgrid.min.js 
    pqgrid.min.css 
    pqgrid.css 
    jquery-ui.css 
    bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css 
    bootstrap.min.css 
    moment.js 
    moment-with-locales.js 
    bootstrap.min.js  
    bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
```

The above order only I am using these files.Here Every js and css files are latest version. But Bootstrap calendar is not visible. When I click a picker, on that time calendar is open but it is hiding inside the paramquery grid.
Please help me how can Start Bootstrap datetimepicker in pqGrid. Please send me a working jsfiddle.

[image]

The above image is the exactly correct one. Here the calendar is visible outside the grid also. This is old version and I have faced lot of issues here. So I will try to use latest version.

The below image is for latest version. Here calendar is not visible outside the grid. I want exactly shown in first image.

[image]

Comment: Check overflow and z-indexes

Comment: I have given "overflow:visible" and z-index also i have increased. But it won't work.

Comment: From the screen shot it seems like the datepicker is being opened in the upward direction .. try opening it in downward direction if such option is available

Comment: Did you try `widgetPositioning { vertical: 'bottom'; }`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rtzxsa3e/20/

Comment: check this fiddle. If I give widgetPositioning { vertical: 'bottom'; } , calendar always open in bottom only. I want to visible both bottom or top.

Comment: In downward direction also it is hiding downside.

Comment: Please look at this fiddle. It is showing the issue what I am facing. Please modify this fiddle  and send me a proper working fiddle.